# AWS Glue Job Failed: An error occurred calling o71.getDynamicFrame..SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect .s3..connect timed out

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

I am trying to create a simple Glue job to move data from S3 to my Redshift cluster for testing purposes but get the following error. An error occurred while calling o71.getDynamicFrame. com.amazon.ws.emr.hadoop.fs.shaded.com.amazonaws.SdkClientException: Unable to execute HTTP request: Connect to ***.s3.amazonaws.com [***.s3.amazonaws.com/***] failed: connect timed out.

The crawler to S3 and Redshift have both worked successfully as well as the Redshift connection. I have a role that I am using that has AmazonS3FullAccess, AWSGlueServiceRole, and AmazonRedshiftFullAccess. I also have a endpoint to S3 and my VPC has a security group that gives permission to itself.

Any help on what this error means and solution?

Thanks

Comment: The creation of s3 bucket in same region where your glue job is, can be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The last time I encountered this was because I deployed the job to a public subnet. Since the glue job only has a private IP address it could not route to the internet gateway. Deploying the job to a private subnet instead, with a route to the NAT gateway, worked though.

Comment: Im curious though to why the test connection of redshift works if thats the case.

Answer (score 0):

Timeout usually occurs when there is no internet access. As Abdul mentioned, Please make sure if your glue connection uses a private subnet.

Also, Ensure that you have a VPC end point for "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3" and the following inbound and outbound rules attached to the associated Security Group.

**Self referential Inbound Rule:**
{"Type":"All TCP","Protocol":"TCP","Port Range":"0-65535","Destination":"Security-group" }

**Outbound Rule:**
{"Type":"All Traffic","Protocol":"ALL","Port Range":"ALL","Destination":"0.0.0.0/0" }

If the issue still exists, then we will have to look at the configuration of Internet Gateway.